# How the "undefined var" error in a set can be solved?

Tags: julia

would you please help me how can I solve the undefined var error in the following code:

```
Beta
6×3×3 Array{Array{Int64,1},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]  [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]  [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
 [5, 3, 6]        [5, 3, 6]        [5, 3, 6]
 [6]              [6]              [6]
 [2, 5, 3, 6]     [2, 5, 3, 6]     [2, 5, 3, 6]
 [3, 6]           [3, 6]           [3, 6]
 [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]  [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]  [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
[:, :, 2] =
 [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]  [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]  [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
 [5, 3, 6]        [5, 3, 6]        [5, 3, 6]
 [6]              [6]              [6]
 [2, 5, 3, 6]     [2, 5, 3, 6]     [2, 5, 3, 6]
 [3, 6]           [3, 6]           [3, 6]
 [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]  [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]  [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
[:, :, 3] =
 [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]  [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]  [4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
 [5, 3, 6]        [5, 3, 6]        [5, 3, 6]
 [6]              [6]              [6]
 [2, 5, 3, 6]     [2, 5, 3, 6]     [2, 5, 3, 6]
 [3, 6]           [3, 6]           [3, 6]
 [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]  [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]  [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
```

Beta is an array matrix and d matrix as follow:

```
d=[    0.0  105.0  119.0   55.0  123.0  44.0
     105.0    0.0   76.0  135.0   42.0  81.0
     119.0   76.0    0.0  170.0   42.0  76.0
      55.0  135.0  170.0    0.0  164.0  97.0
     123.0   42.0   42.0  164.0    0.0  86.0
      44.0   81.0   76.0   97.0   86.0   0.0];

sum(d[i,j]*x[i,j,k,t] for i in 1:6,j in Set(Beta[i,k,t]), t in 1:3, k in 1:3 )

ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JuliaPro-0.6.4.
1\pkgs-0.6.4.1\v0.6\Atom\src\repl.jl:118 [inlined]
 [2] anonymous at .\<missing>:?
```

why this error is happened? if you don't mind please help me about that error . thanks

Comment: put `for` instead of `,` in front of `j in`

Comment: Thanks verrry muuuch :). is this correct?  `sum(d[i,j]*x[i,j,k,t] for i in V,t in H,k in K for j in Set(Beta[i,k,t]))`

Comment: This should be OK (I cannot run your code, as it is incomplete, but it looks OK).

Comment: It was run. yes, it is correct. Thank you

Comment: I have added a reference to the Julia manual as an answer (so that the question does not show as unanswered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required functionality is explained in [Generator Expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#Generator-Expressions-1) section of the Julia manual:

> Ranges in generators and comprehensions can depend on previous ranges by writing multiple for keywords:

```
julia> [(i,j) for i=1:3 for j=1:i]
6-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 1)
 (2, 2)
 (3, 1)
 (3, 2)
 (3, 3)
```

> In such cases, the result is always 1-d.